# Not.. neither... either

Tags: grammar

the "not.. neither.." issue is pretty common, but I cannot seem to wrap
my mind around the following particular case.

I have the sentence:

```
Then, in lines 6–9 of the algorithm, we add edges to E (if not existing in E
and, thus, neither in E')), such that.. bla bla.
```

I want to state that if the edges do not belong to the set of edges E, then they will not belong to the set of edges E' either. It is a consequence.

I suppose a correct way to say it would be:

```
Then, in lines 6–9 of the algorithm, we add edges to E (if not existing in E 
and, thus, not existing in E' either)), such that.. bla bla.
```

But I want to keep it as short as possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, in lines 6–9 of the algorithm, we add edges to E (if not
>   existing in E and thus neither in E'), such that...

and

> Then, in lines 6–9 of the algorithm, we add edges to E (if not
>   existing in E and thus not in E' either), such that...

and

> Then, in lines 6–9 of the algorithm, we add edges to E (if not
>   existing in E and thus not in E'), such that...

are all correct. For brevity, we may use the last.

Comment: Thanx, so it seems my first attempt was correct after all :) 

English is not my native language and it bugged me for some reason..

Comment: My comment would be that "thus neither" is not necessary, and that "thus not in E' " is sufficient. If you are not comfortable with "thus", you can use "therefore" or the simple "so", or the simple "then".